# Create custom numbering in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that includes these columns:

```
track    track_id
-----------------
1        1
1        1
0        2
1        2
1        2
0        3
1        3
1        3
0        4
0        5
....
```

I have the column `track` and want to calculate `track_id`, which would be:
Starting by 1, every time `track` is 0, `track_id` should be incremented by 1 (0 specifies the beginning of a new track).

I wish I could set a variable and then increment it every time the condition is true, but there does't seem to be a simple way to do that.

I would appreciate a query that can pull this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need a column that specifies the ordering.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Let me assume you have such a column, which I'll just call `id`.

Then, you can use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*, 1 + sum( (track = 0)::int ) over (order by id) as track_id
from t;
```

If `track` only takes on the values 0 and 1, you can simplify this even more:

```
select t.*, 1 + sum(1 - track) over (order by id) as track_id
from t;
```